# Regex coding with pattern

Tags: regex

I have a long string `url`, and in it somewhere is "http://www.webcitation.org/65aOmhrdM". I need to write a regex to find "65aOmhrdM" (the pattern is always num,num,lowercase,uppercase,lowercase,lowercase,lowercase,lowercase,uppercase).

I'm looking to say:

`var matches = url.match(/regex here/);`

Thanks.

Comment: Well, `/[0-9][0-9][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z]/` matches the blob you described in Basic or Extended notation, which will work with any language or parser, but do you want your output to be the whole URL, or just the string?  And what language is this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex for the pattern you gave:

```
\d{2}[a-z][A-Z][a-z]{4}[A-Z]
```

If you want to pull it from that url you could do something like this:

```
/http:\/\/www.webcitation.org\/(\d{2}[a-z][A-Z][a-z]{4}[A-Z])/
```

Answer (score 1):

`\\d{2}[a-z][A-Z][a-z]{4}[A-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

Regular is:

```
\d\d[a-z][A-Z][a-z]{4}[A-Z]
```